# SQL string '00000' displaying as '0'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone explain why

```
CASE 
   WHEN MARK = 'Y' 
     THEN LEFT('00000', 5-LEN(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, START, FINISH))) + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, START, FINISH) 
     ELSE '00000' 
END AS [Time]
```

Is displaying as a single `0` instead of `00000` when `Mark <> 'Y'`, and displaying `35` instead of `00035` (as an example)

Comment: Why not `RIGHT('00000'+DATEDIFF(MINUTE, START, FINISH),5)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess SQL is converting it to an integer.

Code like this `select cast('00000' as varchar)` returns as you wish (00000, 00035) but `select cast('00000' as int)` returns your results (0, 35 etc)

Comment: `CAST(RIGHT('00000' + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ADTM, SDTM), 5) AS VARCHAR) AS TEST` is returning 35 still

Comment: Ah figured it out, had to encapsulate the Datediff with the cast

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are using MSSQL server. If, yes then the default datatype for any variable or nullable column is INT